# Where to store Plugin specific information in the database

Tags: plugin-development

My plugin needs to store a value (timestamp) in the database. The value isn't associated with any post/page/etc. Its associated with the plugin. Where should I write this value to the database - what table?

I've used `add_post_meta();` before and this works well to store information associated with a post/page. Is there something similar to write plugin specific information? Maybe a `add_plugin_meta()`?

Answer (score 0):

Store it in `wp_options()` using [`update_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/) and retrieve it with [`get_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/):

```
update_option( 'my_plugin_timestamp', $value );

$value = get_option( 'my_plugin_timestamp' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a single value then use the code below..

```
update_option( 'plugin_timestamp_data', $timestamp);
$timestamp = get_option( 'plugin_timestamp_data' );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option

---

You can use custom table to store your timestamp data if you want to save multiple entries ..

```
//Define table name to use everywhere
define( 'TABLE_NAME', 'plugin_timestamp_data' );
```

Here is the code to initialize the plugin

```
global $jal_db_version;
$jal_db_version = '1.0';

function jal_install() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $jal_db_version;

    $table_name = TABLE_NAME;

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id    BIGINT(20)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time  DATETIME    NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );

    add_option( 'jal_db_version', $jal_db_version );
}

//Calling the activation hook
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'jal_install' );
```

In order to delete the data on plugin uninstall, use the following code..

```
function jal_uninstall() {
  global $wpdb;
  $table_name = TABLE_NAME;

  $dropsql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$table_name};";
  $wpdb->query( $dropsql );
}
//Calling the deactivation hook
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'jal_uninstall' );
```

To add timestamp value just declare the function below in your plugin file and call it where ever you want..

```
function jal_insert_record ($timestamp) {
  global $wpdb;
  $table_name = TABLE_NAME;

  $wpdb->insert(
    $table_name, 
    array(
      'time' => $timestamp
    ) 
  ); 
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins